# display user input in pop up window (Java)

Tags: java, string, input, text, event-handling

The program I have takes a user input and prints it out. What I have done is that I got the text from the textFields and I put them to a toString() method, then I printed them out onto the pop up box. What my issue is that the outputs on the popup box is not what I wanted it to be. The program starts spitting out the original string that is put in the textfield and a bunch of random text right after it (like a bunch of specifications of the text and its position, etc) I am unsure of why this is happening, regular strings or texts work fine but why does retrieved text do this weird display?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private TextField startDate;
    private Text start;
    private Text end;
    private TextField endDate;
    private Button count;



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        start = new Text("Start Date: ");
        end = new Text("End Date: ");

        start.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));
        end.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));

        startDate = new TextField("1/1/2000");
        endDate = new TextField("12/06/2020");

        startDate.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));
        endDate.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));

        count = new Button("Count");
        count.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));

        ButtonEvent ButtonEvent = new ButtonEvent();
        count.setOnAction(ButtonEvent);

        HBox startLine = new HBox(10);
        startLine.getChildren().addAll(start, startDate);
        startLine.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        HBox endLine = new HBox(10);
        endLine.getChildren().addAll(end, endDate);
        endLine.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox button = new HBox();
        button.getChildren().add(count);
        button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(startLine, endLine, button);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        Pane root = new Pane();

        root.getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 130);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Date Counter");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class ButtonEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

        private Text startInput;
        private Text endInput;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            startInput = new Text();
            endInput = new Text();

            startInput.setText(startDate.getText());
            String startDateInput = startInput.toString();

            endInput.setText(endDate.getText());
            String endDateInput = endDate.toString();

            Text test1 = new Text(startDateInput);
            test1.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));
            Text test2 = new Text(endDateInput);
            test2.setFont(Font.font("Arial"));

            Stage msg = new Stage();
            msg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);

            dialogVbox.getChildren().addAll(test1, test2);

            Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 200);
            msg.setScene(dialogScene);
            msg.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you fix `endDate = new TextField("12/06/2020);` to `endDate = new TextField("12/06/2020");`?

Comment: @ofek nice catch ;) fixed already

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `getText` method instead of `toString` on your `Text` objects.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#getText--

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the toString() to getText():

Instead of

```
startInput.setText(startDate.getText());
String startDateInput = startInput.toString();

endInput.setText(endDate.getText());
String endDateInput = endDate.toString();
```

write

```
startInput.setText(startDate.getText());
String startDateInput = startInput.getText();

endInput.setText(endDate.getText());
String endDateInput = endDate.getText();
```